# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Source code in inner folder

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using the EB CLI to deploy to Elastic Beanstalk.

My git repo has this structure

```
|folder1
|folder2
...
|ebs
  |src
  - app.js
```

So I would need to configure (I assume using .ebextensions) EB that the 'ebs' folder is where app.js resides.

Is this doable ?